# What is a better way of writing this SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query like this,

```
select Client_Id, Driver_Id
  from Trips
 where Client_Id not in (select Users_Id from Users where Banned = 'Yes')
   and Driver_Id not in (select Users_Id from Users where Banned = 'Yes')
```

I tried the following, but that gives me an error. Why? If this is not possible, what is a better way to write this query?

```
select Client_Id, Driver_Id
  from Trips
 where Client_Id not in (select Users_Id from Users where Banned = 'Yes') banned
   and Driver_Id not in banned
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN` because it works better when there are `NULL` values.  It can also have better performance.  So:

```
select t.Client_Id, t.Driver_Id
from Trips t
where not exists (select 1
                  from users u
                  where t.Client_Id = u.Users_Id and
                        u.Banned = 'Yes'
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from users u
                  where t.Driver_Id = u.Users_Id and
                        u.Banned = 'Yes'
                 );
```

Note that all column references are *qualified*, meaning that the table alias is part of the column reference.  That is also a best practice.

From a performance perspective, you want an index on `users(user_id, banned)`.

This seems like a good way to write the query.  Attempting to simplify the query to:

```
where not exists (select 1
                  from users u
                  where (t.Client_Id = u.Users_Id or
                         t.Driver_Id = u.Users_Id
                        ) and
                        u.Banned = 'Yes'
                 )
```

Would probably kill performance because `or` is often a performance killer in correlated subqueries and joins.

Answer (score 2):

Considering User_ID as Primary/Unique Key, using joins instead of where clause, in my personal experience, has a lot more difference in speed rather using where clause.  Therefore, what my suggestion would be to write the query serving the same purpose would be as follows:-

```
select T.Client_Id, T.Driver_Id from Trips T
  Left Join Users UC On T.Client_ID=UC.Users_ID and UC.Banned='Yes'
  Left Join Users UD On T.Driver_ID=UD.Users_ID and UC.Banned='Yes'
 where UC.User_ID Is Null and UD.User_ID Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could use a common table expression and NOT EXISTS.  Something like this

```
with users_cte(Users_Id) as (
    select Users_Id from Users where Banned = 'Yes')
select t.Client_Id, t.Driver_Id
from Trips t
where not exists (select 1 from users_cte uc where t.Client_Id=uc.Users_Id)
      and not exists (select 1 from users_cte uc where t.Driver_Id=uc.Users_Id);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eae2f1695869c607d281eebc2af58713)